# expand a string in JavaScript to display letter and how many times that letter appears

Tags: javascript, string, run-length-encoding

> Write a function that accepts a string where letters are grouped together and returns new string with each letter followed by a count of the number of times it appears.
> example : ('aeebbccd') should produce // 'a1e2b2c2d1'

```
function strExpand(str) {
  let results = ""

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let charAt = str.charAt(i)
    let count = 0

    results += charAt
    for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
      if (str.charAt(j) === charAt) {
        count++;

      }
    }

    results += count;
  }

  return results;
}
```

with the input `'aeebbccd'` I am getting `'a1e2e2b2b2c2c2d1'` instead of `'a1e2b2c2d1'`

Comment: Your `j` should start at `i + 1`. You should change your `i` if the character is duplicated. Also, this can be done in one line with regex. `str.replace(/[a-z]+/g, m => m[0] + m.length)`

Comment: The outer loop needs to skip over all the repeated characters that were processed by the inner loop.

Comment: FYI, this is the compression function, not the expansion function.

Answer (score 2):

This function is adding a number after each character, which is the number of times this character appears anywhere in the string. You could instead do it like this to get the result you want.

```
function strExpand(str) {
  let output = "";
  
  // Iterate through each character of the string, appending
  // to the output string each time
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let count = 1;

    // If the next character is the same, increase the count
    // and increment the index in the string
    while (str[i + 1] == str[i]) {
      count++;
      i++;
    }

    // Add the character and the count to the output string
    output += str[i] + count;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) by matching all consecutive groups of the same character and passing a callback that returns the character concatenated to the length of the group.

```js
const fn = str => str.replace(/(.)\1*/g, (g, c) => c + g.length);
console.log(fn('aeebbccd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness,
how about a Regex?

```js
const pattern = /(.)\1*/g; // put a char that exists in a capture group, then see if it repeats directly after
const s = 'aeebbccd';
var result = '';
for (match of s.match(pattern)) {
  let this_group = match;
  let this_len = match.length;
  result = result + this_group[0] + this_len; // get only the first letter from the group
}
console.log(result); // a1e2b2c2d1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would to the job. edit: hah i see im late :D, but still nice functional way to solve that.

```js
/**
 * @param string to count
 * @return string $characterA$count. ex. abbccc -> a1b2c3
 */
function toCharacterCountString(str) {
    return Array.from(new Set(str).values())
        .map(char => {
            return `${char}${(str.match(new RegExp(char, "g")) || []).length}`;
        }).join('');
}


console.log(toCharacterCountString('abbccc')); // a1b2c3
console.log(toCharacterCountString('aeebbccd')); // a1e2b2c2d1
```